# Wildcard Subdomains Break SSL on Other Sites

Tags: ssl, iis, url-rewriting, dns

NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

I enabled wildcard subdomains for one of my sites using IIS 8.5 on a Windows Server 2012 computer. To do this I had to create a wildcard DNS cname and a wildcard binding in IIS. The website is working great, but all of a sudden the SSL has broken on every other site hosted on that server.

I cannot find any tips that might fix this. I checked my bindings and the other sites clearly say to use their SSL certificates for their host names.

My best guest is that by creating a catch all for the first website I somehow did something that IIS interpreted as a command to use site one's SSL certificate for all domains on that IP address. How do I override this?

My DNS for the wildcard subdomains is a CNAME record with * for the host name. My bindings for that include a https binding on port 443 for hostname *. This allows stuff like https://sub.domain.com to use domain.com's SSL certificate. The problem is that now https://domain2.com is also using the first certificate even though it has binding for hostname domain2 to use its own certificate.

I have tried checking the bindings to make sure they use the host names of the other sites and include their SSL certificates.

There is no code to show since it is all done in Windows DNS managers and IIS manager.

The expected result is for sites to use their own SSL certificates if their bindings say to do so even if there is a binding for one site using a wildcard host name.

What I cannot do is upgrade to Windows Server 2016 and use their IIS 10 wildcard subdomain bindings because my hosting company refuses to upgrade.

Comment: It looks like this error can be removed if I remove one of the bindings on site 1 but the problem is that without that binding the subdomains return a 404. The binding properties are: type: https, IP Address: myipaddress, port:443, hostname: *, SSL Certificate: *.site1.com

Comment: This problem is just like this one but I don't see this guy solving it either https://forums.iis.net/t/1237971.aspx?SNI+Wildcard+SSL+Wrong+certificate+served+

Comment: It looks like a problem in which SNI cannot be used for the wildcard so it does not consider it for the others either and serves all sites the same certificate. Right now the only ways around this I see are to change hosts to one that supports WS 2016 or buy a new wildcard certificate that covers all the sites.

Comment: This is getting weirder because rebooting the system fixes this temporarily. Everything works fine for a few minutes until IIS starts serving the wrong certificates again.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming (see [sf] instead for example) but in any case add your further details as edit in the question, not as comments. Please also use RFC 2606 guidance for fake names, do not use things like `domain.com`, `domain2.com`, `site1.com`, etc. as those all exists. In most cases you will get better reply by not obfuscating names.

Comment: could you share your iis site binding detail and certificate detail? try to enable require server name identification checkbox in iis [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Fuc.png) and clear the cache and history and try to browse the site.